# Install the right python version for Spark

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, apache-spark

I use Python 2.7.6 on my machine

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

I have on my machine Spark 1.1.0 depended from Python 2.7.6. If I execute:

```
user@user:~/bin/spark-1.1.0$ ./bin/pyspark
```

I get

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
.
.
.
```

Today I install the new pre-built version of Spark 1.3.1 (I don't know why, but depended from python 2.7.5). If I execute now the same command for the new version:

```
user@user:~/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6$ ./bin/pyspark
```

I get back the older Python version

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 18 2014, 09:37:37) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
.
.
.
```

The main difference is that in the older Spark version I can execute `import numpy`, in the new one not.

I created the next path for Python in `.bashrc` file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:usr/lib/python2.7
```

I don't find the way to distinguish between version 2.7.6 and 2.7.5 in Python, thus I don't know a place, where python 2.7.6 is stored (command `find` is missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with the removing of python2.7.5 from HD. The topic can be closed

Answer (score 0):

You can set the python executable which is used in pyspark and spark-submit by an environmet variable "PYSPARK_PYTHON".

For example,

PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/local/python-2.7/bin/python pyspark

Answer (score 0):

I run this and it worked perfectly fine. "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3"